# What should I do to fix homebrew?

Tags: macos, homebrew

I installed apache-spark 1.6.1 lately and then I uninstalled it and update homebrew to install apache-spark 2.0.0. However, When I run `brew doctor` I don't get any helpful diagnostics about what is wrong:

```
Error: No such file or directory - /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.6.1
```

What should  I do now? The version of my os is 10.11.6.

Answer (score 4):

You have broken links. Homebrew has built in repair utility.
`brew doctor`
After brew finishes the doctor utility, run prune to update & fix homebrew's sym links.
`brew prune`

Comment: It doesn't work for me because the same warning shows immediately after these two command.

Comment: for future readers `brew prune` is by default disabled. Use `brew cleanup` instead

Answer (score 0):

That is as expected

You "I installed apache-spark 1.6.1 lately and then I uninstalled it" so  uninstalled apache-spark 1.6.1 which deletes /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.6.1

Installing apache-spark 2.0.0. will install in /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.0.0

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain what the problem is. My problem is when I want to install some software else or use brew update or brew doctor, the same warning shows all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the SPARK_HOME environment variable set to the wrong folder. You can check by running the following command in the shell:

```
echo $SPARK_HOME
```

If this outputs the '/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.6.1' folder, than that's your problem. To fix, just run the following command in terminal:

```
export SPARK_HOME="/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.0.1/libexec/"
```

or put it somewhere in your .bashrc file. (or whatever dotfile you use).